# Can I count occurances of x per unique id?

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-bigquery

For an ecommerce site I'm trying to run a query on BigQuery that gives me the number of times a customer viewed the product that was finally purchased and get that number for each purchase.

So for one purchase an example:
Visitor X with uniqueId '567890abcdef' purchased product 'A1234', how many times was this product viewed by this visitor in the browsing history.

I could probably get this result for one specific purchase, but I don't how to do this for all purchases from e.g. yesterday. Below i added the query to get all of the purchases. So i would like to know product views per fullvisitorid per productcode.

The first query below will get all bookings for a specific date.
The second query will get the amount of times a specific visitorid has viewed a specific product.

Basically what i would like to see is a query to 'loop through' for all the combinations of visitorid and productid of the purchased product and get me the times the product was viewed.

```html
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  visitId,
  visitStartTime,
  date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 16 THEN hits.customdimensions.value END) productCode
  
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-4-4'), TIMESTAMP('2016-4-4'))
WHERE
  hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  fullvisitorid,
  visitId,
  visitStartTime,
  date
```

```html
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 16 THEN hits.customdimensions.value END) productCode,
  count(totals.hits)
  
  
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxxxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-4-4'), TIMESTAMP('2016-4-4'))

where
  (hits.customdimensions.index = 16 and hits.customdimensions.value contains productCode) and
  fullvisitorid contains 'xxxxxxx'

GROUP BY
  fullvisitorid
```

Comment: i think you should provide more info on tables that hold these info. most likely you have two tables: something like purchases and browsing_history

Comment: Show your tables schema

Comment: the complete schema is found here:https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en